# Can you use ng-dblclick in ng-repeat?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-ng-click

I have an ng-repeat with both ng-click and ng-dblclick. 
I get an error with the ng-dblclick

```
<a ng-repeat="item in list" ng-dblclick="{{item.dblClick}}"></a>
```

The browser console error

```
Error: [$parse:syntax] Syntax Error: Token '{' invalid key at column 2 of the expression [{{item.dblClick}}] starting at [{item.dblClick}}].
```

Comment: remove interpolation from ng-dblclick,  ng-dblclick="item.dblClick"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ng-dblclick` will accept function name as an expression. Interpolation will not work with it.

Try this.

```
<a ng-repeat="item in list" ng-dblclick="item.dblClick()"></a>
```

Comment: You don't need to use this or the `[]` syntax.